# "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when trying to use predicate with a relationshipobject

Tags: ios, swift, object, core-data, predicate

I have the classes Tema, Oppgave and Fag. One Fag has many Oppgaves and one Tema has many Oppgaves. However, every Oppgave in a Tema has the same Fag.

I want to display only the Temas where its Oppgaves has a certain Fag.

These are my relevant models:

```
class Oppgave: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var isArchived: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var isComplete: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var lflink: String
    @NSManaged var link: String
    @NSManaged var nokkel: String
    @NSManaged var oppgaveNr: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var sett: Sett
    @NSManaged var tema: Tema
    @NSManaged var fag: Fag

}

class Tema: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var title: String
    @NSManaged var oppgave: NSSet

}

class Fag: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var title: String
    @NSManaged var fagKode: String
    @NSManaged var isUnlocked: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var oppgave: NSSet

}
```

This is my fetchrequest:

```
    //This variable gets a value from a prepareForSegue function earlier
    var fag:Fag!

    var temaer:[Tema] = []
    var fetchResultController:NSFetchedResultsController!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println("Oppgaver fetches fra databasen")
        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tema")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        //This is the line thats giving me the error
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "oppgave.allObjects.first?.fag.fagKode == %@", fag.fagKode)




        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext{
            fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
            fetchResultController.delegate = self

            var e:NSError?
            var result = fetchResultController.performFetch(&e)
            temaer = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects as! [Tema]


            if result != true{
                println(e?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

    }
```

How can i get rid of the errors and retrieve the objects i want to?

Answer (score 0):

Since all `Oppgave` for the same `Tema` have the same `Fag`, your requirement, "the Temas where its Oppgaves has a certain Fag", is equivalent to "the Temas where ANY of its Oppgaves has a certain Fag", for which the predicate is:

```
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY oppgave.fag == %@", fag)
```